# Content filter in a webpage when content is presented through bootstrap grid system

Tags: javascript, html, filter, filtering

I have bunch of rows each containing a fixed number of columns. Here rows and columns refer to twitter bootstrap's grid system. I want to filter data from these cells when the user enters something into the search box located in the same page in real time. This is very similar to list.js instead the data is not presented in lists/columns but instead through the grid system of bootstrap.

An example of one of the rows is:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <figure style="text-align: center">
          <img src="projects/2015/images/1.jpg" width="80%" class="img-thumbnail">
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="caption">
              <a id="caption1" style="cursor: pointer" >Assessing Public ...</a>
            </h4>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p id="abstract1" style="display: none" class="abstract">
                In the ....
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <figure style="text-align: center">
          <img src="projects/2015/images/2.jpg" width="80%" class="img-thumbnail">
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="caption">
              <a id="caption2" style="cursor: pointer">Feasibility of...</a>
            </h4>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p id="abstract2" style="display: none" class="abstract">
            Community-based businesses...
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <figure style="text-align: center">
          <img src="projects/2015/images/3.jpg" width="80%" class="img-thumbnail">
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="caption">
              <a id="caption3" style="cursor: pointer">Improving Agricultural Practices in Farm Lands in Mandi through Technology</a>
            </h4>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p id="abstract3" style="display: none" class="abstract">
                    Agriculture is...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, how can I filter such content like list.js filters list. The content will be filtered based on the data presented in the captions and abstracts.